# Batch mergin mkv video with subtitles using MKVToolNix

Tags: batch-jobs, mkvtoolnix

For one file I know I can (being my video and sub files in the same directory):

```
mkvmerge -o output-file.mkv --default-track 0 --language 0:es subtitle-file.ass video-file.mkv
```

But how can I do the same for 50 files. My video and subtitle files name are the same:

video-1.mkv
video-2.mkv
video-3.mkv
video-1.ass
video-2.ass
video-3.ass

And my output file should be something like video-1-sub-mkv, video-2-sub-mkv, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each `XYZ.mkv` has a corresponding `XYZ.ass`, it's possible to use a `for` loop:

```bsh
for i in *.mkv; do
    if [ -f "${i%.*}".ass ] && [ ! -e "${i%.*}"-sub.mkv ]; then
        mkvmerge -o "${i%.*}"-sub.mkv "$i" --default-track 0 --language 0:es "${i%.*}".ass
    fi
done
```

- Note: I did rearrange the order of your input files, so that the `ass` track is added after tracks from the `mkv`